# Image Texture Mapping Issue

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to map smudges onto a material but it's only mapping on one surface of the object.

For clarity I've shown it here as a checker pattern. The cube is fine, but the image texture is not mapping correctly to the bottom left object.

[image]

---

Screenshot showing the material nodes editor.

[image: material nodes]

Comment: please share your file (and pack the images if there are some: File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Screenshots are not enough descriptive to locate your issue. Moonboots is right - share some simplified  version of your blend if you still expect solution from community.